# Unable to get information to be pulled in dependant on user

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables set up in SQL... One for users, which works for users to log in and out completely fine...

And another to pull a timetable into a html table, which works fine when a user isn't specified... But I'm trying to include a WHERE statement to make only information with the correct user_id (in the timetable) to show, dependant on the users session id.

I'm only receiving errors with this line...

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_table ORDER BY Number WHERE $_SESSION['user_id']";
```

$result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

Any advice on where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing a query with wrong syntax.

The query should be like

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY Number";
```

Comment: I'll give that a try now!

Comment: Thanks so much Krishna, it worked straight away! Still getting my head around all of this (fairly new to me!) so, sorry if it seemed like a bit of a basic mistake.

Comment: NP.it will happen when you start learning. you cannot learn without making mistake.Also plz accept my answer.

Comment: StackOverflow has a time limit that has to pass before I can accept.... Just waiting on it to tick over :)